# Create error after checking inside map and find functions in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, async-await

It's difficult to describe my question, but probably who works with it should understand.

I have a piece of code

```
const response = await client.getEntries({content_type:'user'});
let userData = response.items.map(i => i.fields).find(obj =>{
  return obj.email == user;
})
```

It works very well if "obj.email" equals "user". But if not, I don't get the response. So how can I add here some kind of an error handle? It may look easy, but I'm stuck with it.

My solution from Deep Kakkar help

```
if(obj.email == user)
      return true;
    else
      return obj.email = "user";  // "user" can be anything (incorrect email)
```

Comment: why are you using `map` either you simply do this as `response.items.find(obj => (obj.fields||{}).email == user)`

Comment: I think the problem is not here, the problem is where you are sending response or there may be error due to `userData` which breaks the code and the compiler won't reach `res.send` you can surround the code in `try{}catch(err){res.send("nodata")}` block

Comment: Mo, you are right!

Comment: @Vova you can just [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) as the solution rather than mention the solution itself in the question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try the code :

I can see the problem occurs for that case if the condition `obj.email == user` failed.  Here you can put a IF Else condition to handle it.

```
const response = await client.getEntries({content_type:'user'});
  let userData = response.items.map(i => i.fields).find(obj =>{
    if(obj.email == user)
      return true;
    else
      return obj.email = "user";
  })
```

Comment: Thanks Deep, you help me understand) I've done like it -> if(obj.email == user)
      return true;
    else
      return obj.email = "user"; Because my next function said me that "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined"

Comment: For the next function,  you need to either edit the question or ask a new question on StackOverflow :)